# Calling curl with a variable in the link returns a blank line

Tags: shell, curl, scripting, grep, sh

I'm attempting to make a small shell script to fetch information off of the c++ reference website and I want to crawl through the different pages of the website. To do this i've written the following code:

```sh
curl -s http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ | grep -oP '(?<=<a href= ").*?(?=">)'
```

This successfully fetches the child pages of a given page however inputting all the links manually is tedious so I attempted to do this:

```sh
URL="algorithm" # <-- will be turned into an array
cr=$"\r"
URL=${URL%$cr}
#for loop:
curl "http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/${URL}"
#done
```

But when I attempt to run this, the file returns a blank line, how would one go about implementing this functionally?

Comment: So you want to curl every child page?

Comment: If you're getting a line per URL of output, note that the better practice would be as described in [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) instead of using a `for` loop (or if you _do_ want a `for`, loading your data into an array and looping over the array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iteratively curl all the returned child pages you can store the child pages in a variable and run a for loop for each child in the variable. You can then use that url inside the for loop and use it in the curl command.

```sh
childs=$(curl -s http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ | grep -oP '(?<=<a href= ").*?(?=">)')
declare -a array=($childs)
for url in "${array[@]}"
do
    curl "http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/$url" 
done
```

EDIT: using array as noted by Charles

Comment: Note that `for url in $childs` is a code smell -- in general, it's bad form to store a _list_ inside a _string_; in well-designed code, lists should be stored in arrays, so items aren't subject to word-splitting and globbing (with their behavior depending on the current value of IFS and local filesystems contents and thus being prone to surprises)

Comment: `declare -a array=$(childs)` has the same word-splitting behavior. Consider instead `readarray -t array < <(curl ... | grep -oP ...)`, or if compatibility with bash 3.x is required, `IFS=$'\n' read -r -a array < <(curl ... | grep -oP ...)`.

Comment: ...see also [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `wget` instead of `curl`.
It fetches all the linked pages automatically.
Use

```
wget -r -l 1 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/
```

`-r` is for recursive. `-l 1` is for the level of recursivness.